# Ubuntu 14 and PXE - Variable to pass to specify install path?

Tags: 14.04, server, pxe

I'm trying to get Ubuntu 14.04.3 server to install from a PXE menu - this has been a massive headache.

I just need to know where I specify the path to the install files, that's it.

Currently the installer is downloading everything from archive.ubuntu.com (this takes HOURS), even though I have a perfectly valid local http address set in a preseed file:

```
d-i     mirror/country          string          us
d-i     mirror/protocol         string          http
d-i     mirror/http/hostname    string          foo.com
d-i     mirror/http/directory   string          /ubuntu/14.04.3/mnt/
```

I've tested "http://foo.com/ubuntu/14.04.3/mnt/" locally, and it works fine.

I've also tried passing the parameter via the PXE menu:

```
LABEL ubuntu-14.04.3-server_mnt-x86_64
        kernel /ubuntu/14.04.3/linux
        MENU LABEL ubuntu-14.04.3-server_mnt-x86_64
        append initrd=/ubuntu/14.04.3/initrd.gz ksdevice=bootif lang=  text  auto-install/enable=true priority=critical url=http://foo.com/ubuntu/14.04.3/mnt/ domain=local.lan suite=trusty
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I struggled with this for a long time. The key for me was the   addition of "live-installer/net-image=" argument below. (thanks to a reply from Chakri in http://www.michaelm.info/blog/?p=1378). So below is what worked for me. I downloaded the server image for 14.04.3 and placed it in the "ubuntu" directory at the root of my http server:

in pxelinux.cfg/default

```
default menu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 15
serial --unit=0 --speed=115200 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1
terminal --timeout=0 serial console

MENU TITLE PXE Menu

label install
menu label ^Install (from my http server)
menu default
    kernel ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8
    append ks=http://192.168.1.1/KS/ks_ubuntu.cfg vga=normal initrd=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz live-installer/net-image=http://192.168.1.1/ubuntu/install/filesystem.squashfs
```

in the kickstart file ks_ubuntu.cfg in directory "KS" at the root of my http server

```
install
url --url http://192.168.1.1/ubuntu
```